# Spark SQL - java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: empty.init when casting column

Tags: java, scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I am getting the following error when trying to perform a cast on a column (read from a comma separated csv file with headers).

Here is the code I am using:

```
var df = spark.read.option("header","true").option("delimiter",",").csv("/user/sample/data")
df.withColumn("columnCast", expr("CAST(SaleAmount) AS LONG")).count
```

This causes the following exception to be thrown every time. I've tried different columns when casting and some throw while others do not. I've also tried the following which also throws the same exception.

```
df.withColumn("columnCast", expr("CAST(NULL) AS LONG")).count
```

> java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: empty.init
>     at scala.collection.TraversableLike$class.init(TraversableLike.scala:451)
>     at scala.collection.mutable.ArrayOps$ofInt.scala$collection$IndexedSeqOptimized$$super$init(ArrayOps.scala:234)
>     at scala.collection.IndexedSeqOptimized$class.init(IndexedSeqOptimized.scala:135)
>     at scala.collection.mutable.ArrayOps$ofInt.init(ArrayOps.scala:234)
>     at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.analysis.FunctionRegistry$$anonfun$7$$anonfun$11.apply(FunctionRegistry.scala:565)
>     at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.analysis.FunctionRegistry$$anonfun$7$$anonfun$11.apply(FunctionRegistry.scala:558)
>     at scala.Option.getOrElse(Option.scala:121)

I have tried running this both in spark-shell and zeppelin. Spark version is 2.4.0.cloudera2 managed by Cloudera.

What is causing this behaviour? Is this intended? How do I handle this?

Comment: Can you run `spark-shell --version` and include the output to your question? Also, can you run `spark-shell` and execute `spark.catalog.listFunctions.count`? What's the output? I think there's something wrong with the Spark environment and any query would simply fail.

Comment: That exception looks like [SPARK-28521](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-28521) that happens in 2.4.3 and got resolved in 3.0.0 (that is not available yet).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use column's cast method to do the cast:

```
import spark.implicits._

val df = spark.sparkContext.parallelize(1 to 10).toDF("col1")
val casted = df.withColumn("test", lit(null).cast("string"))
               .withColumn("testCast", $"test".cast("long"))
casted.show()
casted.printSchema()
```

Result:

```
+----+----+--------+
|col1|test|testCast|
+----+----+--------+
|   1|null|    null|
|   2|null|    null|
|   3|null|    null|
|   4|null|    null|
|   5|null|    null|
|   6|null|    null|
|   7|null|    null|
|   8|null|    null|
|   9|null|    null|
|  10|null|    null|
+----+----+--------+

root
 |-- col1: integer (nullable = false)
 |-- test: string (nullable = true)
 |-- testCast: long (nullable = true)
```

Comment: At this time this looks to be the best workaround until they can address the sql string syntax error.